# how to rewrite url in asp.net for the beginners?

Tags: asp.net

I am not able to rewrite url using following code. As I am new to asp.net, am confused with various code that I have found in google.

```
<system.webServer>

<defaultDocument>
<files>
<clear/>
<add value="Default.aspx"/>
</files>
</defaultDocument>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
<add name="UrlRewriter" 
type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule"/>
</modules>

<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

</system.webServer>

<rewriter>
<rewrite url="~/vendor1.aspx?id=1" to="~/products.aspx?category=books" />
</rewriter>
```

Comment: there is no such thing as `</rewriter>`. Use the `<rewrite>` tag. Also go through this url https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: instead of <rewriter> tag??

Answer (score 0):

To rewrite URLs in ASP.NET we are going to use HTTP Modules. HTTP Modules are called before and after the HTTP handler executes. HTTP modules help us to intercept, participate in, or modify each individual request. HTTP Modules implement an IHttpModule interface, which is located in the System.Web namespace. Modules are the ones which handles authentication and authorization of the ASP.NET applications. If you want to implement encryption of the URL string or any custom changes to the application, it can be done by writing our HTTP Module.

Visite http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/akkiraju/url-rewriting-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: thank you. Now i am getting another error :"The configuration section 'UrlRewriter' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration".